# Quarkus + GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, graphql, quarkus

Tengo dos clases de entidades Usuario y Helado, dos clases service UsuarioService y GraphqlService. Dentro de la clase UsuarioService tengo un metodo llamado addUsuario que agregar un cliente y se le asigna un helado por ID la cosa es que cuando creo mas de un usuario se le borran los helados a los usuarios creados previamente y solo el usuario final queda con helados asignados.

**UsuarioSerivce:**

```
@Transactional
public void addUsuario(Usuario usuario, List<Long> heladoIds) {
    for (Long heladoId : heladoIds) {
        Helado helado = Helado.findById(heladoId);
        if (helado == null) {
            throw new GraphQLException("El helado con ID " + heladoId + " no existe");
        }
        usuario.addHelado(helado);
        helado.setUsuario(usuario);
    }
    usuario.persist();
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

**GraphqlService**

```
    @Mutation
public Usuario createUsuario(@Name("usuario") Usuario usuario, @Name("heladoIds") List<Long> heladoIds) throws GraphQLException {
    String nombre = usuario.getNombre();
    String patron = "^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patron);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nombre);

    if (!matcher.matches() || usuario.getNombre().isEmpty()) {
        throw new GraphQLException("El nombre no debe contener números ni caracteres especiales");
    }
    if (usuario.getEmail() == null || usuario.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
        throw new GraphQLException("El campo email no puede estar vacío.");
    }
    usuarioService.addUsuario(usuario, heladoIds);
    return usuario;
}
```

*La clase usuario Omitire los getter y setters de las demas variables*:

**Usuario**

```
@Entity
public class Usuario extends PanacheEntityBase{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Helado> helados = new ArrayList<>();

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(List<Helado> helados) {
    for (Helado helado : helados) {
        helado.setUsuario(this);
    }

    public void addHelado(Helado helado) {
        helados.add(helado);
        helado.setUsuario(this);
    }

    public void removeHelado(Helado helado) {
        helados.remove(helado);
        helado.setUsuario(null);
    }

    public List<Helado> getHelados() {
        return helados;
    }

    public void setHelados(List<Helado> helados) {
        this.helados = helados;
    }
```

}
La clase Helado tambien omitire getter y setters solo para que se entienda la relación

**Helado**

```
@Entity
public class Helado extends PanacheEntityBase{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
private Usuario usuario;
}
// constructor, getter & setter
```